# Finding sum of all integral parts

Tags: contest-math, summation, integer-programming

Given two numbers $M$ and $N$, Let $q_i$ be the integer part of $\frac{iN}{M}$. What is 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{M-1} q_i?
$$
The Sum is obviously can be calculated in $O(M)$. Can this be done in less time, maybe $O(1)$ if there exists some simpler reduced expression?

Comment: Why is it $O(M)$? If $N=M$, the sum is $M(M-1)/2$, which is $O(M^2)$.

Comment: Is there any special relationship between M and N?  For example, if M and N are coprime, I believe the calculation could be done in O(1) time.

Comment: I edited... It was sum to calculated in O(M)

Comment: I got the solution. It is O(log n*log m).
sum = (NM - N - M + gcd(N, M))/2)

Comment: @Shashwat If you have an answer, write it down. wait for comment for a while and then accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming M and N are integers, I believe your formula can be rewritten as

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M-1}\frac{iN}M-\frac1M\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M-1}iN \mod M.$$

The first sum is an arithmetic sum.  There is a formula for arithmetic sums that can be done in O(1) time.  The second summation is the sum of remainders from the division.  If $N$ and $M$ are coprime, no 2 of these remainders are the same, reducing the sum to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{M-1}i$, which is another arithmetic sum.

I'm sure the formula can be adjusted in the case where $M$ and $N$ are not coprime.  Maybe someone else can fill in the blanks while I'm getting some sleep, assuming you're interested.  My guess is if you know nothing about M and N, your computation time will stem from performing the Euclidean algorithm to obtain a gcd, which I believe should be less than linear time.